# Ability to embed safari browser in a native mobile application

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

Is it possible to embed the safari browser or a downloadable browser such as Google Chrome into a native mobile application? For example, the app runs entirely independent, but has the option to open the safari browser within the application, rather than opening the Safari that is installed into the phone.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in iOS. Use a UIWebView instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use webviews instead and here is a list of 3rd party webviews which have more or less the same as safari iphone https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=webview